# What solution function Postgresql regexp_split_to_table in Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, postgresql, function

In PostgreSQL have a function

```
Select id, regexp_split_to_table(meta_value) from metas;
```

Date:

```
1, '45,46,47'
2, '10'
3, ''
4, '12,4558,456'
```

Need same result

```
1, '45'
1, '45'
1, '47'
2, '10'
3, ''
4, '12'
4, '4558'
4, '456'
```

What Solution for Mysql?

Is link [One Column](https://forums.mysql.com/read.php?10,635524,635529) but result in one column, need two or more columns

Answer (score 0):

Try using substring_index function

```
select   id,   substring_index(substring_index(meta_value, ',', n),     ',',     -1  
) as meta_value
from metas join metas   on char_length(meta_value)     - 
char_length(replace(meta_value, ',', ''))     >= n - 1
```